# Check if the expected object is of backend CUDA or CPU?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

> - I am trying to run a code on both CPU and CUDA.
> - The problem arise when I create objects, as I need to know what's expected.

I need to determine if the computer is expecting a CUDA or CPU tensor, before it is created.

Code:

```
def initilize(self, input):
     self.x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros((1,M))

def run(self,x,state):
  B = torch.cat((self.x,h)
```

This outputs:

```
Error: 'Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #1'
```

Code idea:

```
def initilize(self, input):
  device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
  if (expecting_cuda == True):
     self.x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros((1,M)).to(device))
  else
     self.x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros((1,M))

def run(self,h):
  B = torch.cat((self.x,h)
```

- Question:
  How to figure out what the computer expects?
- Limitations:
  I am running on a pre-defined "check" procedure, so I can not send an argument into the function 'initilize' with information about CUDA or CPU.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `self.x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros((1,M)).to(device))`, no need for `if (expecting_cuda == True):` because `to(device)` will also work for cpu.